# jQuery/Ajax POST with ContentEditable spans not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I hate JavaScript/jQuery.... and, most days it hates me.  Just when I think we're starting to build a rapport, I fall down a hole I can't find my way out of.

I'm trying to have ContentEditable spans POST changes to MySQL onBlur.

**Here's my HTML/PHP:**

```
<h4><strong>Number of Employees: </strong><span contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'NumberOfEmployees','<?php echo $row["mysqlid"]; ?>')"><?php echo number_format($row['numberofemployees']); ?></span></h4>
```

**Here's my jQuery:**

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            var dataString = 'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "_updatelead.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { dataString },
                } 
            }
           });
```

I can't find my error, but every attempt I make throws the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: saveToDatabase is not defined
>       at HTMLSpanElement.onblur (viewleaddetail.php?id=5658:225)

Any ideas how I can resolve this?  It seems to be  a simple answer, but I can't get it right.  Thanks!

Comment: sounds like it has nothing to do with contenteditable, it has to do how you defined your function.

Comment: Hello, looks like the function `saveToDatabase` isn't reached, you should define it "globally"

Comment: Is the function definition before the markup that tries to use it in the inline binding?

Comment: Your construction of the data element is also invalid syntax.  You can give it just an object, and $.ajax will convert it into a query string.

Comment: @Taplar the function is actually at the end of the page, so it's not before the markup.  I removed the {} around the dataString, and I've set the function inside a $(document).ready tag to make it global, but it's still generating the same error

Comment: Inline bindings, as far as I remember, require the functions to be defined before they are used, not after, and they must exist in the global namespace. There is the potential here to change how you are binding to avoid this issue if you bound dynamically and not with an inline binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you use  jQuery why don't you try like this:

**HTML**

```
<h4><strong>Number of Employees: </strong>
  <span contenteditable="true" class="emp_item">
    <input type="hidden" value="NumberOfEmployees" name="column">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo number_format($row['numberofemployees']); ?>" name="editval">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['mysqlid']; ?>" name="id">    
    <?php echo number_format($row['numberofemployees']); ?>
  </span> 
</h4>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).on('blur', ".emp_item", function () { 

    var dataString =  $(this).find(":input").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "_updatelead.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { dataString }
            });

});
```

Comment: How does that work...?  What input is it getting?  All of the inputs are hidden... so, what updated information is it posting?  I see where you're echoing out the current value, but I'm trying to make it possible for the user to be able to edit the current value and have that edited value post to the database onBlur......

Comment: in your code user only can see numberofemployees. it post all the information in the hidden inputs

Comment: yeah, that doesn't work either.... If I'm reading your code correctly, the jQuery is looking for a change in an input field to POST.  Well, the user isn't interacting with any input fields.... they're changing an editable span.  So, that code doesn't even trigger an event.